# python md5 encryption using the update function with a variable

Tags: python, encryption, md5

I have:

```
import hashlib
md5_object = hashlib.md5()
string = input("Enter a string to encrypt: ")
md5_object.update(b,string)
secret_code = md5_object.hexdigest()
```

how do you pass variables to the `update()` function that are strings?

Comment: According to documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html the 'b' is required. Not sure what is does but it makes it work.

Answer (score 2):

Just encode your string to UTF-8:

```
import hashlib
md5_object = hashlib.md5()
string = input("Enter a string to encrypt: ")
md5_object.update(string.encode("utf-8"))
secret_code = md5_object.hexdigest()
```

Otherwise, you will get this error:

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```